# Android MediaPlayer warnings when looping a sound

Tags: android, audio, media-player

I am getting warning messages in the log file.  I continuously play a looping sound during gameplay (and adjust the volume).  The log message seems to be produced when the sound is being looped (every 2 secs or so).  It is a normal .wav file and it plays as expected.

```
squishSound = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.juicy);
squishSound.setVolume(0, 0);
squishSound.setLooping(true);
squishSound.start();
```

This produces a log message every 2 seconds: -

> 05-16 15:31:23.745:
>   WARN/MediaPlayer(10356): info/warning
>   (1, 44)
>
> 05-16 15:31:26.112:
>   WARN/MediaPlayer(10356): info/warning
>   (1, 44)
>
> 05-16 15:31:28.479:
>   WARN/MediaPlayer(10356): info/warning
>   (1, 44)
>
> 05-16 15:31:30.846:
>   WARN/MediaPlayer(10356): info/warning
>   (1, 44)
>
> 05-16 15:31:33.221:
>   WARN/MediaPlayer(10356): info/warning
>   (1, 44)
>
> 05-16 15:31:35.589:
>   WARN/MediaPlayer(10356): info/warning
>   (1, 44)

I have searched, but I can't find any reason why this would happen.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is OK, and probably notifies that the file is replayed.

Comment: Seems a bit unnecessary and completely clutters up the log file, is there any way to stop it happening?

Comment: You can filter the log if you want. Filtering by tag is helpful many times anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I am currently filtering, but it's hard when 3rd party libs are potentially writing to the log too (I am trying to debug why adwhirl isn't working atm)

Comment: You can create a few filters, or filter by pid, nothing more helpful then that I afraid...